# Using DBFit variables for other Fixtures

Tags: rest, testing, fitnesse

Is it possible to use a DbFit variable in another fixture? For example, if I create a query in dbfit with a variable `<<firstname` as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM System.Columns Where ColumnName= 'FirstName' | <<firstname |
```

Is it possible to include a reference to that page in another suite of tests that use a column fixture or RestFixture and call the variable name to check against the database?

In the RestFixture, I'm checking a database column name against a node so can I do something like:

```
| GET | /resources/6 | | //${firstname}  |
```

Where I'm checking if an `xml` node named FirstName exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

With fitSharp (.NET), it is.  With Java, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue, imo it's hard to find any good documentation. I stumbled upon the answer skimming some arbitrary tests somewhere.

You can access the symbol in RESTFixture using *%variablename%*.

RestFixture

```
| GET | /resources/6 | | //%firstname%  |
```